# Accessing gradle resources from Java

Tags: java, resources, gradle

I have a gradle-based java project with this structure

```
.
├── myproject
│      ├── src
│      |    └── main
│      |         ├── java
│      |         └── resources
│      |               └── myresource.xml
|      ├── build
|      |     ├── classes
|      |     |    └── main
│      |     |         └── myresource.xml
|      |     ├── resources
```

I'm trying to access some files in the *resources* folder using a ClassLoader, like this

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResoure("/myresource.xml");
```

but it does not find the file.

The only way I have found to access those files is by exploring the known structure of the project

```
Path resourcesPath= FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "/src/main/resources/");
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, it seems my difficulties came from another problem (resources not being copied to the proper places). Once I solved that problem, the ClassLoader was able to find my resources using either of these two forms:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("./myresource.xml");

ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("myresource.xml");
```

**Edit:** When using the jar embedded in other applications, the former solution do not work, use this in that case:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myresource.xml")
```

Comment: Doesn't work when you're trying to load resources from a jar. See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-read-setup-resources-from-plugin-jar/13274/2.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

For example something like `MyMain.class.getResource("/config.txt")` or use relative path when appropriate.

Comment: I have modified the original question for clarification and better understanding

Comment: The classes are stored in the same place, as  resources do.

Comment: You are right @DmitryGinzburg, my difficulties were due to the resources not being copied to the classes folder, it was a problem related to the use or configuration of gradle in my IDE, I guess (I'm new to gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use it this way:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myresource.xml")
```

If i use `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("myresource.xml")`

When I use it as a jar package embedded in other applications, I still have no access to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to access Java resources in the `build.gradle` with in Gradle in Groovy is to do for example to read `VERSION` file in the Java resources:

```
static String getVersion(File rootFile)  {
    File versionFile = new File(rootFile, "src/main/resources/VERSION")
    byte[] versionBytes = Files.readAllBytes(versionFile.toPath())
    String version = new String(versionBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim()
    version
}

version = getVersion(project.projectDir)
```

It avoids manipulating the `ClassLoader`.

*Note: `sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir` does not exist yet in function of the task.*