# Accessing resource in Java/Gradle Environment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, resources

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940815/accessing-gradle-resources-from-java?rq=1) question but unfortunately, their answer didn't work for me. I have a gradle-based java project too with the following structure

```
.
├── myproject
│      ├── src
│      |    └── main
│      |         ├── java
│      |         └── resources
│      |               └── templates
│      |                      └── myresource.bmp
|      ├── build
|      |     ├── classes
|      |     └── resources
|      |          └── main
│      |               └── templates
│      |                      └── myresource.bmp
```

Since I want to run my code on Android and Windows, I'm accessing the resources with the following

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
res = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("templates/myresource.bmp");
```

This worked previously with Eclipse, because I just put my resources into the src-folder and it was copied to the target directory. But when migrating to Android Studio and Gradle, I moved the resources into the resources folder, where I thought they would belong and it's now no longer under the src/ path.

Now, whenever I execute that code, I only get null. To me it seems, that the path is somewhat incorrect. I tried the following paths:

- /myresource.bmp
- myresource.bmp
- template/myresource.bmp
- resources/templates/myresource.bmp
- ../../resources/main/templates/myresource.bmp

but nothing seems to work.

Maybe I'm using the wrong classloader, but it actually looks ok.
[image: ClassLoader debugging paths]

What would be the correct path, to load the resources? One more thing to mention: The project 'myproject' is in my case a library that loads the resources and it is called from another test-project, if that is somehow relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct path would be `/templates/myresource.bmp`.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727998/1743880.

Comment: Nope... didn't work. Maybe the classLoader is wrong then. Note that the resources are in `C:\ProjectA\src\main\resources\templates\myresource.bmp` and copied to `C:\ProjectA\build\resources\main\templates\myresource.bmp`.

Comment: `/main/templates/myresources.bmp` it is then. The absolute path starts from the `classes` or `resources` directory.